# Python restore file from executed file memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, memory, system

I wrote a long python script and executed it. The problem is now that the file is deleted and I can't recover it. I still can see the process of my script is still running with a simple command "ps aux | grep my_script.py". Is there any way to restore my file from that executed script process?

OS: Linux Ubuntu 19.10
Python version: Anaconda based, 3.7.4

Thanks

Comment: Check the `/proc/` folder of the process to see if there's still a file handle open. You might be able to read it.

Comment: @KlausD. unfortunately, I can't find it. cd to /proc/{process_id} then grep -rw "def main*" without good result